# ange-ftp problem on cygwin emacs

Tags: microsoft-windows, cygwin, ftp

I've hit a brick wall with this.  I'm running cygwin on a Windows 7 machine.  I can't connect vai ange-ftp to an ftp server, hosted by godaddy.com.  I do C-x C-f /username@ftp.foo.com: (to get a dir listing) or :index.html (file exists), and in both cases emacs asks me for my password, I enter it, and then emacs freezes.  Hard freezes - only way to kill it is to use Task Manager, and kill two emacs-w32 processes.

I'm using the cygwin emacs-w32 program.

My `.emacs` includes `(require 'cygwin-mount)`.  I also tried `(require 'setup-cygwin)` (downloaded most recent version today), but that doesn't load properly.  Error about "cannot find cygwin", having to do with a variable that sets the path to cygwin.  I couldn't figure it out so commented out `(require 'setup-cygwin)`.

So - suggestions?  Could this relate to what ftp client emacs / ange-ftp is finding?  Other things about my emacs setup for cygwin?  I've been using cygwin emacs for about 6 months and most other things work, including running processes from within emacs (shell, tex, grep, diff, etc).

Thanks.

Here's the result of `emacs-w32 --debug-init` with `(require 'steup-cygwin)` in my .emacs.  Alas I can't give any error info on the actual ange-ftp issue, since emacs just freezes.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  file-directory-p(nil)
  (and (file-directory-p directory) (file-readable-p directory) directory)
  setcyg-dir-p(nil)
  (if (setcyg-dir-p cygwin-root-directory) nil (error "Cannot find Cygwin.  Please customize option `cygwin-root-directory'"))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-780625> nil "/cygdrive/c/Users/strozzi2/.emacs.d/lisp/setup-cygwin.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 4972
  load-with-code-conversion("/cygdrive/c/Users/strozzi2/.emacs.d/lisp/setup-cygwin.el" "/cygdrive/c/Users/strozzi2/.emacs.d/lisp/setup-cygwin.el" nil t)
  require(setup-cygwin)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/cygdrive/c/Users/strozzi2/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1708
  load-with-code-conversion("/cygdrive/c/Users/strozzi2/.emacs" "/cygdrive/c/Users/strozzi2/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262
```

**** With new setup-cygwin.el from Drew, it behaves as he said.  The relevant part of .emacs is:

```
(require 'cygwin-mount)
(setq cygwin-root-directory "/c/cygdrive/cygwin64/")
(require 'setup-cygwin)
```

Startup now works.  C:/cygwin64/ didn't.

And ange-ftp works!  Once I put ftp in passive mode to get around firewall.  Success!

Comment: Try to post the exact error message(s). That might help someone help you. And start Emacs using the switch `--debug-init`.

Comment: OK, I just did what you asked.  It may help sort out setup-cygwin, but won't directly address the ange-ftp error.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you the problem, I think:

```
Cannot find Cygwin. Please customize option `cygwin-root-directory'
```

You need to set that variable.  Use **`M-x customize-option RET cygwin-root-directory RET`** to do that.

(That said, the code should have handled a non-string argument to `setcyg-dir-p`. Download the latest [`setup-cygwin.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/setup-cygwin.el) to get that fix.)

Comment: Thanks!  I actually downloaded that file this morning.  So I think the current version gives the error.

Comment: I just updated it, before I wrote that. The error is *correct* - **you need to customize the option**. The minor fix to the code was to return nil if the value is not a string. Your problem does not come from `setup-cygwin.el`; it comes from your not having defined option `cygwin-root-directory`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I forgot to refresh the browser tab viewing that file from yesterday morning.  My fault.  I updated my question with more info.  Now it loads.  On to ange-ftp.

Comment: ange-ftp works now too!  Thanks for your help.